# Wordpress wp_query filter using posts_groupby - how to SUM values in joined table?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Can somebody please help me with a crazy wordpress problem? I'm using wordpress's add_filter to join a second table for my wp_query and I'm trying to get the query to group_by a pageviews column (from a plugin I installed) and SUM them for my output. I'm managing to get the results grouped but the result set only shows one of the values. I would like to know 2 things.

1. Is my join ok for joining the posts table to the wp_popularpostsdata
   table where the wp_popularpostsdata table will have more than one
   entry per post->ID?
2. How do I use the SUM function as I can't see it anywhere in the
   Codex?

I'm having to use wp_query, as opposed to query_posts, as that is what is used for the rest of the output in my client's templates. I tried using wppp.postid as my groupby but it returned no results. Here's my code, hopefully it makes a bit more sense.

Functions in my site plugin:-

```
            function add_filter_7dayspopular(){
            add_filter('posts_where', 'edit_posts_where');
            add_filter('posts_join','edit_posts_join');
            add_filter('posts_groupby','edit_posts_groupby');
            add_filter('posts_orderby','edit_posts_orderby');

            function edit_posts_join($join_statement) {
                global $wpdb;
                remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
                $join_statement .= "LEFT JOIN wp_popularpostsdata wppp ON $wpdb->posts.ID = wppp.postid";
                return $join_statement; 
            }

            function edit_posts_where($where_statement) {
                global $wpdb;
                remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
                $where_statement .= " AND wppp.last_viewed > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . "'";
                return $where_statement;
            }

            function edit_posts_groupby($groupby_statement) {
                global $wpdb;
                remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
                $groupby_statement = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
                return $groupby_statement;
            }

            function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement){
                global $wpdb;
                remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
                $orderby_statement = "wppp.pageviews DESC";
                return $orderby_statement;
            }
            }
```

Here's my new wp_query code:-

```
            add_filter_7dayspopular();
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => array( 
                    'post', 
                    'portfolio'
                    ),
                'post__not_in' => $itemArray,
                'posts_per_page' => $load_more,
                'post_status'=>'publish',
                'orderby' => 'pageviews',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'paged' => $paged
            );
```

Thanks guys.

Mark

Loushou answered the question fully. After running the code the field $post_.total_views is available to use inside my loop. Here's their code with a tiny change by myself:-

```
            // change your orderby function to order by the sum
            function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement){
                global $wpdb;
              remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
              // add sum() around the field name
              $orderby_statement = 'sum(wppp.pageviews) DESC';
              return $orderby_statement;
            }

            // add a posts_fields function
            function edit_posts_fields($fields_statement) {
                global $wpdb;
              remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
              $fields_statement .= ', sum(wppp.pageviews) as total_views';
              return $fields_statement;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWERS**

1. You can do it exactly like this, however as your site grows, this query will take a very long time to run
2. to sum the pageveiws, and order by the sum, do two things:

```php
// change your orderby function to order by the sum
function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement){
  remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
  // add sum() around the field name
  $orderby_statement = "sum(wppp.pageviews) DESC";
  return $orderby_statement;
}

// add a posts_fields function
function edit_posts_fields($fields) {
  remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
  $fields .= ', sum(wppp.pageviews) as total_views';
  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response loushou. Unfortunately, as soon as the posts_fields filter is applied I get no results returned. So, I removed the posts_fields reference but still used your revised orderby and it works. Yay. BUT, any idea how I can display the resultant SUM within the page content?

Comment: Loushou - you're a genius. Thank you very much. I got it all working. The only thing that was missing? A comma in your $fields line!! I've updated my question to show your answer including the tiny fix. Thanks again.

Comment: Does this remove_filter inside the add_filte callback actualyl work? That's a lot cleaner than removing all filters as soon as the code is ran.